# Jquery Table Collapsing

Tags: jquery

I have made a photo gallery,but when the images change it seems the table collapses.

I was hoping someone could check the code on my page and see what is wrong.

The code itself is fairly short.

Thanks

EDIT:This has been answered I no longer wish to post the URL to my site.Hoping this is ok and it does not get voted down to much :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is that you need to give your table rows a height. At the moment they are only achieving a height when there is an image in them. If you give then a defined height they should not collapse.

Comment: Yep. Seems that was the problem. Thanks

Comment: I will as soon as I am able.It won't let me do it right away :-).

Answer (score 0):

Assign 94 px height to tds, and i have also noticed that when all the images are uploaded in firefox the src in image tag cant seem to find the images and the images seem to be broken.